# rpmbuild different path for sysconfdir

Tags: linux, package-management, rpm, rpmbuild

I am building rpm for `opensips` and i want to install this package in `/opt/opensips` path instead of default system path

I have define following in my `SPEC` file

```
    %define _prefix /opt/opensips
    %define _sysconfdir /opt/opensips/etc
    %define _libdir /opt/opensips/lib64
    %define _datadir /opt/opensips/share
    %define _sbindir /opt/opensips/sbin
    %define _bindir /opt/opensips/bin
    %define _mandir /opt/opensips/share/man
    ...
    ...
    ...

    %build
    LOCALBASE=/usr NICER=0 CFLAGS="%{optflags}" %{?_with_oracle:ORAHOME="$ORACLE_HOME"} %{__make} all %{?_smp_mflags} TLS=1 \
      exclude_modules="%EXCLUDE_MODULES" \
      cfg-target=%{_sysconfdir}/opensips/ \
      modules-prefix=%{buildroot}%{_prefix} \
      modules-dir=%{_lib}/%{name}/modules

    %install
    rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
    %{__make} install TLS=1 LIBDIR=%{_lib} \
      exclude_modules="%EXCLUDE_MODULES" \
      basedir=%{buildroot} prefix=%{_prefix} sysconfdir=%{buildroot}/opt/opensips/etc \
      cfg-prefix=%{buildroot} \
      modules-prefix=%{buildroot}/%{_prefix} \
      modules-dir=%{_lib}/%{name}/modules \
      DBTEXTON=yes # fixed dbtext documentation installation
```

I am getting following error when i build RPM

```
rpmbuild -ba opensips.spec
```

Error:

```
RPM build errors:
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/opensips-1.11.1-1.el6.x86_64/opt/opensips/etc/rc.d/init.d/opensips
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/opensips-1.11.1-1.el6.x86_64/opt/opensips/etc/opensips/dictionary.opensips
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/opensips-1.11.1-1.el6.x86_64/opt/opensips/etc/sysconfig/opensips
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/opensips-1.11.1-1.el6.x86_64/opt/opensips/etc/opensips/opensips.cfg
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/opensips-1.11.1-1.el6.x86_64/opt/opensips/etc/opensips/opensipsctlrc
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/opensips-1.11.1-1.el6.x86_64/opt/opensips/etc/opensips/osipsconsolerc
```

If i check my BUILDROOT i can see it put all those file in `/etc` at default location

```
ls -l /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/opensips-1.11.1-1.el6.x86_64/etc/opensips/
```

How do i tell RPM put those files in `/opt/opensips/etc/` directories?

Answer (score 0):

Move the files from /etc/opensips to /opt/opensips them after the "make install" command.

Comment: Manually moving system files is rarely a good idea. In fact, assuming there is a package manager at all, manually messing around in the system is virtually never a good idea.